# Dropbox error: "Unable to monitor entire Dropbox folder hierarchy"

Tags: dropbox

So I've installed dropbox via [this guide](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx), but every time I run `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`, I get the following error:

```
Unable to monitor entire Dropbox folder hierarchy. Please run "echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf; sudo sysctl -p" and restart Dropbox to fix the problem.
```

I have run the command it asks me to, but this error still pops up. I've searched and found [this answer](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Create-upload-and-share/Unable-to-monitor-dropbox-folder/td-p/394555), which explains what's going on.

I have changed the `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` to 1000000 (1 million) as well, but that doesn't seem to work either. What could be going on here?

Comment: how many folders are in your Dropbox?

Comment: even better explanation from stackoverflow, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711897/dropbox-fs-inotify-error . Check if max_user_watches actually got updated to 1 million, and if your dropbox is huge then you may need to increase max_user_watches more.

Comment: @Esther so that answer essentially did what I've already done. The only thing I didn't do was check if it got updated. Currently when I run `sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches` I get `fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 100000` so it hasn't updated. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: @Esther Also there are 320,262 items, totalling 529.9 GB (some contents unreadable) in my Dropbox folder.

Comment: did you try putting it in a file in /etc/sysctl.d instead of /etc/sysctl.conf ? The linked answer says that /etc/sysctl.conf is deprecated and newer systemd won't load it. Possibly the Dropbox program is also old and the message hasn't been updated?

Comment: You may want to check your Dropbox folder for circular links.

Comment: @Esther I didn't, as that appeared to be referring to Arch, so I ignored it. I did try it, and now it seems to be working. At least it's working without errors now. Taking a long time to index all the files though, but that's it's own problem.